# Thumbnails on word wordpress portfolio displaying incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, post

I have just noticed that one of my sites has started displaying thumbnails inconsistently in portfolio galleries (shown in screengrab as not sure if your allowed to post links on here? They should all be the larger version)

[image: screengrab]

I haven't updated anything recently so am unsure why this has suddenly happen after the site being up for 8+ months working how it is supposed to.

Having checked the media library the items with smaller thumbnail images aren't showing up in there but they are still in the relevant ftp folders, so not sure if that means anything?

The obvious solution is to re-add the featured images to each post but I was wondering if there was a quicker way as they are still in the sites structure?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: You can post safe URLs here..also thumbnail sizes are adjustable from backend..check some thumbnail re generation plugins as well

Comment: Thanks swapnesh. They were displaying fine so I dont want to go changing stuff in the backend if there is a simpler solution. this is one of the portfolios in question: http://www.paperworldcards.com/standard-birthday/
The thing that confuses me is that the images are still showing in the ftp but not in the media library?

Comment: any new plugin installed recently or any updates ?? also chk portfolio gallery settings if any

Comment: Nope, haven't touched it for months. Gonna try your plug-in regeneration suggestion. If that doesnt work then a back-up from a few weeks back on test to see if the problem is there too. If that doesn't work then I will try and update wp again. Last resort will be a case of replacing the incorrect images. Unless someone else knows a quicker fix by the time I have tried the above.